# Boat-anchoring: crabbing versus pointing

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the boat-anchoring problem, which deals with whether trying to get to a dock via the crabbing method or via the pointing method takes the shortest time. For a detailed explanation of what these methods are, [click here](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/info/exercises/boat_time.html).

[image]

When solving it, I got these differential equations

$$\begin{aligned} 
  \frac{dr}{dt}      &= u \sin \theta - v\\
  \frac{d\theta}{dt} &= \frac{u\cos \theta}{r}\end{aligned}$$

Problem is solved if I could get from this, $r$ as a function of $t$. How could I solve these differential equations for $r$?

Comment: What are the states? Inputs? Parameters?

Comment: i dont know if that is relevant. r goes from 0 to d is what all i have.

Comment: If you can't be bothered to explain how you arrive at the ODEs, why would anyone bother to invest the time to answer?

Comment: i think u have misunderstood me. r and $\theta$ are functions of t, and u,v and r are constants. Apart from that the only condition i could arrive at is r belongs to the interval [0,d], where d is a constant. If you are asking how i got the ODE, it came directly from the condition that radial velocity is $u\sin \theta - v$ and tangential velocity is $u\cos \theta$. But i thought it would be irelevent from a math point of view. I'm sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Ideally, you explain what each variable and each parameter mean. This allows readers to understand how you modeled the problem to arrive at the ODEs. It gives one the option to find more "natural" coordinates and rewrite the ODEs. At this point, I have zero physical intuition about your problem.

Comment: Try both methods and compare the time required for each of them. This is the only sure way to find out.

Comment: Can't those ODE be solved for an r and theta uniquely?